# Dictionary with multiple same keys with different values python

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, key-value

I have .txt file example this. It's meant to be Name:Money

```
Muumimamma:3.3
Pikku Myy:1.3
Muumimamma:2.9
Niiskuneiti:2.2
Muumimamma:8.9
Muumipappa:3.9
Niiskuneiti:3.8
Muumipeikko:2.2
Muumimamma:1.3
Niiskuneiti:2.0
Muumipeikko:3.2
Muumimamma:5.0
```

I want to make dictionary where the name is key and money is value and if there is the  more than once in the file the money should be added together. So my final dictionary should be like this:

```
{'Muumipappa': 3.9, 'Pikku Myy': 1.3, 'Niiskuneiti': 8.0, 'Muumipeikko': 5.4, 'Muumimamma': 21.4}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us what you have tried and explain why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `collections.Counter` sums the way you want:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('/tmp/myfile.txt') as f:
    d = sum((Counter({k: float(v) for k, v in [line.split(':')]}) for line in f), Counter())

d = dict(d)
```

Note that a counter instance is already a subclass of dict, so the line `d = dict(d)` may not really be necessary depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks! This did the job correctly and was suitable for rest of the code.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this same thing without importing from collections?

Comment: Yes, but don't be scared of imports - especially not from the core libraries.  Trying to do everything in python without imports is foolish indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `defaultdict` from `collections` with `float` (there is an example with `int` in the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict))

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = defaultdict(float)

with open("money.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    name, money = re.split(":",line[:-1])
    d[name] += float(money)
```

Comment: It is not necessary to strip off the newlines with `[:-1]`.  `float()` doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

So we are not allowed to use import. I came up with this idea, what do you think?

```
testi = open(file, "r")
lista = testi.readlines()
testi.close()
dict = {}
for arvo in lista:
    arvo = arvo.strip()
    type = arvo.split(":")
    if type[0] in dict:
        dict[type[0]] += float(type[1])
    else:
        dict[type[0]] = float(type[1])
```

Comment: Who says you are "not allowed" to use import?   This is the correct approach in pure python, but you should follow @fredtantini example for the style.  And don't use `type` as a variable name, because it is an important built-in function.

Comment: My programming teacher said it. "Change your program to use pythons standard dict. Import's use is prohibited, becouse of securityproblems, in future you should only use built-ins, and don't trust the import, unless its told to use them". This is for the introduction to programmin in university of technology. And for the type, i just tried translate those names for something that you understant, becouse they were in my language.